# UITableView Scrolls automatically while textfield begins editing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am developing an iOS app which has different forms which is populated into a UITableview based on users selection. Each form has different fields like Textfield, DatePicker, PickerView. So I used a single TableViewCell (nib) to hold all these and show or hide the items based on question.
There is save function defined which will save values when user enters to an array.

My issue is, at times my tableview scrolls as if the index goes out of control. like when I select any textfield, Tableview scrolls to top. I have removed all keyboard observer methods and checked, still it is happening.

Below is my save function code:

```
 func saveFormValue(mystr: String) {
    //selectedIndex is a global variable (NSIndexPath)
    let dict = sections[selectedIndex!.section].questions![selectedIndex!.row]
    dict.answer = mystr
    sections[selectedIndex!.section].questions![selectedIndex!.row] = dict
    let answer = updated_answer.init(ID: ID, form_id: selected_form_id, form_name: formName, section_id: dict.section_id ?? "",question_id: dict.question_id ?? "", question_name: dict.question_name!,question_type:dict.question_type!)

    updatedArray.append(answer)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

This is the code in textfieldDidBeginEditing function (how selectedIndexPath is initialized):

```
 guard let index = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else {
    return
 }
 selectedIndex = index as NSIndexPath
```

I have added delegate for cell, and one thing I noticed is, this issue is happening whenever I press pickerview or datepicker once. I couldn't see this issue If I only touch textField cells only.

Please let me know for any further details.

Comment: Have you properly manage Keyboard Handling? Your textfield is visible after keyboard appear?

Comment: @gauravbajaj I added keyboard observer function and checked, it is working fine. This issue is happening at times. for eg: in my tableview I have 30 questions. I scrolled down to 20th questions and pressed on textfield of that cell, that time keyboard appears but tableview scrolls to top some other cell.

Comment: Share your keyboard observer function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code hope this helps to you.

```
 if let thisIndexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
    tableView.scrollToRow(at: thisIndexPath, at: .top, animated: false)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

On textfield delegate method `textFieldDidBeginEditing` use the following code:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        let indexParh = NSIndexPath(row: textField.tag, section: 0)
        self.constTBL_Bottom.constant = 260
        self.tblViewObj.scrollToRow(at: indexParh as IndexPath, at: .middle, animated: false)
    }
```

Also you need to manage the table bottom constant. When you resigning your keyboard set table view constant to 0

Hope this will work :)